# Implementing Search

Tags: javascript, url, google-search, google-search-api

This is an extension of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211632/javascript-advanced-search-with-parametrized-url). I want someone to be able to fill in the search form, hit the search button and do the following:

1. Redirect to the url `www.mywebsite.com/search?<params>`
2. Make an ajax call to my backend controllers
3. Display the results on screen

I know how to do #3 obv, but I want to know what's the best practice for doing #1 and #2. Here's the relevant [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1603/). Would I do something like this:

```
function getValues(id) {
    return $("#" + id).val().join(",");
}
$("button").click(function() {
    window.location = <baseurl> + "/search" +
    "?loc=" + getValues("e1") +
    "&type=" + getValues("e2") +
    "&col=" + getValues("e3");
    //Ajax call to api controller
})
```

What is the standard way that someone like google or wikipedia implement searching? How do they route and make their backend call at the same time?

Comment: So you want to execute the search using an AJAX call (i.e. without reloading the page), and also change the window URL?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you want to do either.  What do you mean by:

"How do they route and make their backend call at the same time?"

Comment: As soon as you redirect to a different page, you won't be able to make an ajax call. The ajax call will have to be made by the search page.

Comment: There is no *standard way* that Google and Wikipedia implement searching. They're both customized, Google especially. They've spent billions of dollars refining their search algorithms, and they're strictly proprietary, not *standard*.

Comment: @JohnEllmore My question is how, in general, do you go to a search page like wikipedia, type in the word soccer into the search bar, press enter, and get routed to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football` with information pulled from their db displayed.